# How to read message thread in Java mail?

Tags: gmail, jakarta-mail, email-client, thunderbird, email-threading

I am developing an email client. I have being able to retrieve messages from server (Dovecot imap). I am not able to retrieve or to show  the related reply messages. This concept is know as message thread. Can anyone help me about how to get this message thread in Java mail?

I tried using gimap (Google imap) lib but got confused.

Comment: If the original message is in the Inbox, the reply message would be in the Sent Messages (or similar) folder, is that where you're looking for it?  If the reply is sent by a third person, it might be in the Inbox along with the original message, are you not able to find it there?  Or are you not able to correlate the reply with the original message?

Comment: Thank u for your reply Bill. I am getting all the replies and it is there in my folder. There is no problem with that. The only issue is i am not able to show the related message. EXAMPLE-                                                                 A sends to B ::::: B replies to A ::A replied back::::::                                                Now when B retrieve its messages there are two message send by A. ACtually yes there are two message but i want to know how to find out these two messages are related  ? Hope i make sense ??

Comment: Look at the In-Reply-To and References headers.  There's an RFC that describes them, and I believe another RFC that describes how to sort messages into "threads" or "conversations".

Comment: I tried but could not got one that i understand, so i did it using message reference header.

Comment: @BillShannon   can u please give me your email id, i have few questions to ask you. gigmelepcha9@gmail.com this is my email id if u dont want to reveal yours.

Comment: You can send questions to javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Answer (score 1):

In mails having headers, From those headers one of header name is **References**
Using References headers you can get all thread mails messageids.

message.getHeader("References");

Comment: Consider adding more detail to your answer, as it is it may lack some detail for someone who arrives at this questions without much context.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).